# comparing and extracting attributes and saving in array using perl TWIG

Tags: perl

I am having a huge xml file only a part i am pasting here:

```
<List NAME="ANDREW" ENROLED="2" FEE="640" CONFORMATION="I"> 
 <DATA>
   <HOUSE>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37496" SECTION="A"/>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37496" SECTION="B"/>
   </HOUSE>
  </DATA>
 </List>
 <List NAME="SAM" ENROLED="4" FEE="640"  CONFORMATION="O">
  <DATA>
   <HOUSE>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36816" SECTION="A"/>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36816" SECTION="B"/>
   </HOUSE>
  </DATA>
 </List>
  <List NAME="MATHEW" ENROLED="3" FEE="467" CONFORMATION="I">
 <DATA>
   <HOUSE>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37436" SECTION="A"/>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="37436" SECTION="B"/>
   </HOUSE>
  </DATA>
 </List>
 <List NAME="RAY" ENROLED="1" FEE="982"   CONFORMATION="O">
  <DATA>
   <HOUSE>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36892" SECTION="A"/>
    <PRIMARY GROUP_ID="36892" SECTION="B"/>
   </HOUSE>
  </DATA>
 </List>
```

I am using xml::TWIG

i have to check if "CONFORMATION" is I then get the "FEE" and "GROUP_ID" and store in seperate array
also if "Conformation" is "O" then get the "FREE" and "GROUP_ID" and store them in different array.

```
use XML::Twig;

my $filename = 'report2.txt';

open( $fh, '>', $filename );

my $twig = new XML::Twig(
    twig_roots => {
        "List"                    => \&add,
        "List/DATA/HOUSE/PRIMARY" => \&update
      }
);
$twig->parsefile("file.xml");

#$twig->print;

sub add  {
    my ( $twig, $add ) = @_;    # handlers params are always
    $cond = $add->att('CONFORMATION');
    $cond2 = $add->att('FEE');

    if ( $cond == 'I' ) {
        sub update {
            my ( $twig, $update ) = @_;
            $check = $update->att('GROUP_ID');
            print $fh " GROUP_ID :$check ";
        }
    } elsif ( $cond == 'O' ) {
        sub update {
            my ( $twig, $update ) = @_;
            $check = $update->att('GROUP_ID');
            print $fh " GROUP_ID :$check ";
        }
        print $fh "CONFORMATION=$cond \n GROUP_ID : $cond2";
    }
}
close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

right now i am just trying to print them in log so futher i can move.
but got screwed up.

please help i am begineer to PERL
my code is lyke this which is printing all of them but not in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly - move that `update` sub outside the `add` sub. That's just dirty.

XML::Twig works on having 'handlers' that 'fire off' to parse segments of XML code. It's a really lightweight way of working on a large file, because on of the common problems with XML is that it's really memory hungry.

You're overcomplicating what you're doing though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub process_list {
    my ( $twig, $list ) = @_;
    my $conformation = $list -> att( 'CONFORMATION' );

    my $fee = $list -> att ( 'FEE' );
    foreach my $primary ( $list -> first_child ( 'DATA' ) -> first_child ('HOUSE') -> children() )
    {
        my $group_id = $primary -> att ( 'GROUP_ID' );
        print "$conformation, $fee, $group_id\n";
         ### here you have the information you need to do the rest of your processing. 
    }

}

my $parser = XML::Twig -> new ( 'twig_handers' => { 'List' => \&process_list} );

$parser -> parsefile ( $xml_file );
```

the 'handler' is triggered each time the parser sees a 'List' element, and then you can extract the subelements and attributes you need. `children` gives a list of elements to cycle.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.
while i am running the script it is printing two values but after that its saying can't call method "first_child" on an undefined value ..

Comment: That error means that the 'first_child' method doesn't have anything that matches. Is that by any chance an XML chunk that doesn't have 'DATA' or 'HOUSE' defined? Either way - it's something you might have to tweak your code to trap as it goes.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.
while i am running the script after printing some value ts saying can't call method "first_child" on an undefined value. because there are also other entities available with different title name so how to get rigid of this.

Comment: actually after printing LIST values some other title are defined with other name in xml file.Program is showing error for them. if the whole document have same title and values then it is fine for program to produce output.

Comment: Test whether `$list -> first_child ( 'DATA' )` is defined. Same for the HOUSE tag.

Comment: $list -> first_child ( 'DATA' ) is defined but apart from this some other are also defined for which script is throwing error.
please look into this 
program is putting output for first data once other tags are comming it is showing error.